# Writing down the worst-case running time O(n) of this given code?

Tags: c

I have been given the following code:

```
void sort(int a[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if(a[j] > a[j+1])
                swap(a + j, a + j + 1);
}
```

I have to calculate the worst-case running time O(n) of this code.

n is 20, so I was thinking, is O(n) = 20 - 1, or is it O(n)= n-1?

Comment: This algorithm isn't `O(n)`.

Comment: Neither "20 - 1" nor "n - 1" makes sense as an answer for what the O(N) is of *any* algorithm; and also the *entire point* of this analysis is that you *can't say* things like "n is 20" because you are trying to figure out *how the time taken changes when N changes*. Please review your course notes.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn computer science fundamentals. You could start by putting, for example, "big-o notation" into a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you see a double-nested for loop, your first reaction should be :likely `O(N²)`.

But let's prove it.

Start with the outer loop.  It will iterate `n-1` times.  As `n` gets really large, the `-1` part is negligible. So the outer loop iterates pretty close to `n` iterations.

When `i==0`, the inner loop will iterate n-2 times.  But again, there's not much difference between `n` and `n-2` in terms of scale.  So let's just say it iterates `n` times.

When `i==n-2`, the inner loop will iterate exactly once.

Hence, the inner loop iterates an average of `n/2` times.

Hence, `if(a[j] > a[j+1])` is evaluated approximately `n * n/2` times. Or `n²/2` times.  And for Big-O notation, we only care about the largest polynomial and none of the factors in front of it.  Hence, `O(N²)` is the running time.  Best, worst, and average.